# Fetching data from a Google Drive file's "Activity Dashboard" in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is it possible to fetch data from a Google Drive file's "Activity Dashboard" from a Google Colab notebook?

Ideally, a Google Colab notebook would be able to fetch the unique viewers, views over time, etc. from the "Activity Dashboard" of any Google Drive file.

I have been unable to find any resources on this topic/or determine whether this is supported. Thanks for the suggestions!